# How to send Ajax Call from frontend without using wp_localize_script in Theme

Tags: php, theme-development, ajax, javascript

I have a situation where I've to send Data from frontend without using any Plugin Due to Code is loading on the same page using Ajax so I can't use any plugin Because Plugin files will load on refreshing of the file but the page is not loading.

I am using **post snippet plugin** to sending PHP and JS to the page which is loading on the page.
**PHP Code is:-**

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
global $current_user;
$unit_id= get_the_ID();
$userid = $current_user->ID;
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM wp_prepze_video_limits WHERE user_id =$userid && unit_id = $unit_id");
$counter = $results->counter; 
if($counter!=0)
    {
        echo $counter;
    }
else
{
    $myObj->counter = $counter;
    $myObj->unit = $unit_id;
    $myObj->user = $userid;
    $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
    echo $myJSON;
}
}
```

**JS CODE is:-**

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function(){
        var counter = [uname][/uname]; //This is post snippet Name that outputs Above PHP Code in here
        var user_counter;
        if(counter.counter==null)
        {
            user_counter = 0;   
        }
        //var user_counter= counter.counter;
        var unit_id = counter.unit;
        var user = counter.user;
        var ajax= counter.ajax_url ;
        jQuery.ajax({

            url : AjaxUrl,// I'm Not Sure Where do I Send the Request
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'post_love_add_love',
                unit_id : unit_id,
                user_counter : user_counter,
                user : user,

            },
            success : function( response ) {
                //jQuery('#love-count').html( response );
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

**I am not sure about where do, I send this request.**

Comment: You have to make a function named `post_love_add_love` and add add ajax action `add_action('wp_ajax_post_love_add_love','post_love_add_love');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post_love_add_love,'post_love_add_love';`

Comment: Where do I put this code, What should be the `url : AjaxUrl` in the AJax Request from the Script

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script('ur_js_id',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/your.js');`
`wp_localize_script('ur_js_id','ajax_object',array('ajax_url'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));`
----------------------
`url : ajax_object.ajax_url,`
---------------------------------
`add_action('wp_ajax_post_love_add_love','post_love_add_love'‌​);` `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post_love_add_love,'post_love_add‌​_love');`

`function post_love_add_love(){
'your code'
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    url : postlove.ajax_url,
                    type : 'post',
                    data : {
                        action : 'post_love_add_love',
                        unit_id : unit,
                        user_counter : new_counter,
                        user : user,

                    },
                    success : function( response ) {
                        //jQuery('#love-count').html( response );
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
```

This Works for me. Thanks